# Can somebody help me with mysql query for fibonacci series

Tags: mysql, fibonacci

Query to print Fibonacci Series in SQL unto 100 terms

0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, ……..

Comment: Common recursive CTE.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
    SELECT 1 id, CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(65, 0)) fibonacci, CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(65, 0)) previous
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1, 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id + 1, fibonacci + previous , fibonacci
    FROM cte
    WHERE id < 100
      AND fibonacci
)
SELECT id, fibonacci
FROM cte
ORDER BY id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f741adaa3ff24b4fbebbe96293213cdb

`CAST` sets the datatype and avoids an overflow.

First 2 subqueries sets static fibonacci numbers. Recursive part generates all another numbers.

Condition by `id` sets the amount of numbers to be generated (313 max). Condition by `fibonacci` excludes 1st number from recurse processing.